# citation at the end of minipage rather than at the end of frame

Tags: beamer, numbering, citing, minipage

[image]I have been going through various help pages to solve the problems that I am encountering using `beamer` presentation but unsuccessful so far. I'm using `minipage` to insert a figure and some texts in `beamer` presentation. I am also using a bibtex file to call the references automatically using `\footfullcite`. As shown in the picture, the references come at the end of `minipage` rather than at the end of the frame.Also, the numbering as 'a' whereas my previous slide has citation number as 5. So in brief, if anyone could help me in the following 2 points, it would be much appreciated. (I have already tried `\footnotemark`, `\footnotetext{\fullcite{citeKey}}` but doest get the output I want)

1. automatic citiation from bibtex file at the end of the frame/slide
2. continuous numbering from the previous frame

MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{movie15}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{subfig,epsfig,float}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,sorting=none,backref=true,style=numeric,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{parnotes}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}

\addbibresource{ReferencePHD.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{\iffootnote{\color{red}\tiny}{\color{blue}}} % To change color to blue
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{title}}  % To clear the title of the journal
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{editor}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{address}}

\date{\textbf{February 10, 2017}}

\begin{document}
 %-------------------------------------------- Frame 1--------------------------------------- 
 \begin{frame} 
     \frametitle{Simulation parameters}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight]{./Sim_para}
\end{minipage}%%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
    \item MATLAB \footfullcite{matlab} is used.
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}% %
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Citation problem using minipage]

Comment: The image link at the end of the question refers to a not existing image. Could you either add the image or remove the link? And can you remove all preamble code that is not needed for the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `\footcitetext` the command you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[sorting=none,backref=true,style=verbose,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\date{February 10, 2017}
\setbeamerfont{date in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame} 
    \frametitle{Simulation parameters}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth,height=0.8\textheight]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}%%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item MATLAB\footnotemark{} is used.
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}% %
    \footcitetext{moore}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: :Thank you very much for the answer. Making the changes, viz., style=verbose, \footnotemark{} and \footcitetext{citekey} worked perfectly for me.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work, if I have multiple citations in the minipage.